# Radius of curvature from points that define a curve in the cartesian coordinate system

Tags: kinematics, curvature

My question is very similar to this one: [Radius of curvature](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/190262/254156).

The only difference is that in this case instead of a known curvature *y*, we have points x and y on a cartesian coordinate system that define a curve.

How does one calculate the radius of the curvature in this case?

Comment: The answer to that question gives the radius of curvature at each point of an arbitrary curve $y(x)$. Isn’t that what you are asking for?

Comment: See here https://opentextbc.ca/calculusv3openstax/chapter/arc-length-and-curvature/

Comment: @G.Smith Correct. I should have mentioned that in my question.